# Let $q$ be an integer $\geq 3$. Prove that there are infinitely many primes $p$ with $p\not\equiv 1 \mod q$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I know that a proof for infinitely many primes has everything to do with Euclid's proof. For example, there are infinitely many primes $p\equiv 1 \mod 4$, or even $1\mod q$, is something I know how to do. But how to show it is $\textit{not}$ equivalent to $1 \mod q$?

Hope someone can help!

Comment: Hint:  suppose you had a list of all of them. Try to construct an integer which is not divisible by any of those but which is not $1\pmod q$.

Comment: Note:  it's considerably harder to show that there are infinitely many primes $\equiv 1 \pmod q$. There's a simple trick that works for $4$, but not for larger $q$.  If you know a simple method for showing that, please post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume otherwise and let $p_1,\ldots,p_n$ be the complete list of primes that are $\not\equiv 1\pmod q$.
Let $N=p_1\cdots p_n$ be the product of these primes. Then $N\pm 1$ is not divisible by any $p_i$, hence is the product of primes $\equiv 1\pmod q$ only, hence $N\pm 1\equiv 1\pmod q$ and so $2=(N+1)-(N-1)\equiv 0\pmod q$.

Comment: Can't one of $N\pm 1$ also be divisible by $q$ if $q$ is prime? I thought you could multiply all primes (including $q$ if $q\lt p_n$ is prime, and add $q$ as an explicit factor if not) up to $p_n$ to get a product $N$ and then $N-1$ must have a suitable factor?

Answer (score 1):

Take a number $k\in\{2,3,\ldots,q-1\}$ which is coprime with $q$ and consider the sequence$$k,k+q,k+2q,k+3q,\ldots$$By [Dirichlet's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions), this sequence has infinitely many primes and it is clear that no such prime $p$ is such that $p\equiv1\pmod q$.